# Returning one of the two Partial View from Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my view I am rendering partial view for registration form:

```
<div class="col-md-8 regform">
            @Html.Partial("_RegistrationForm",Model)
        </div>
```

Now when user submit the form I am using ajax to call the controller. The controller check if the mode is free from error. If there is error controller returns Partial view with model for registration. But if there is no error then controller return different partial view. Below is my Ajx call:

```
 $("#registrationform").submit(function (e) {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '/Members/Register/',
                   data: $("#registrationform").serialize(),
                   success: function (data) {
                       $('.regform').html(data);
                   }
               });

               e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
           });
```

**Controller**

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.CountryList = ISOCountryHelper.Instance.getAllCountries();
                model.StateList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                model.CityList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                return PartialView("_RegistrationForm",model);
            }

            //do other stuff
            model.UserCreated = true;
            return PartialView("_Notifications", model);
```

Now the problem is when there is errors in model then the view work fine shows error and registration form. But if there is now error and controller return _Notification partial view then div tag regform is not getting replaced with "_Notification" partial view. Instead the partial view is appearing in new page. I want it to render in same page in a div tag regform. 
Any idea what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that the partial view that is not working does not have a Layout property set at the top of it, as that will render it as a full, not partial view. You can compare to the one that does work